# Missing owncloud sync and pgp encryption in geary

Tags: openpgp

I use elementary since 2 year (luna, freya) but I really miss a owncloud sync (like google or facebook sync) for files, calendar. An owncloud sync of photos and music whould be great.

Also I miss an addressbook (like dexter) and an easy pgp encryption for geary.

Thank you, Ing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the owncloud sync client `.deb`-file, which you can download at your owncloud page. To sync your calendar you can use the CalDAV-Link from the owncloud calendar app and import it into the desktop calendar app from eOS.